# Can't get the last-child to work in my css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply a different background for the last h3 element with this css and I don't understand why it won't work:

```
#s5_accordion_menu h3:last-child {
 background-color:#000000!;
 }
```

this is the html

```
<div id="s5_accordion_menu">
<div>

<h3 id='current' class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/shooting-tips.html" >
<span>Shooting Tips</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
    <h3 class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/stickhandling-tips.html" ><span>Stickhandling / Passing Tips</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
    <h3 class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/skating.html" ><span>Skating Tips</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
    <h3 class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/skating-2.html" ><span>Training Tips</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
    <h3 class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/skating-3.html" ><span>Training Aid Drills</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
    <h3 class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/skating-4.html" ><span>Product Reviews</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
    <h3 class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/skating-5.html" ><span>HockeyShot Commercials</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
    <h3 class='s5_am_toggler'><span class="s5_accordion_menu_left"><a class="mainlevel" href="/skating-6.html" ><span>Contest - Promos</span></a></span></h3>
<div class='s5_accordion_menu_element' style='display: none; border:none; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px'></div>
```

Any idea how I could manage to get a diffrent background for that last h3 tag?

By the way this works for the first h3 tag:

```
#s5_accordion_menu div h3:first-child {
background-color:#000000;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`h3:last-child` means "A element of type 'h3' that is the last child of its parent". It does not mean "The last element of type 'h3' in its parent". Since you have a `div` after your `h3`, the `h3` is not the last child.

You want [`:last-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo)

Comment: Don't forget to mention that :last-of-type does only work for IE 9 and greater

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use something more specifc, you can use `:nth-child(n)` where `"n"` is the element number, or a function like `"(n + 1)"`.